# JSF - Trinidad versus MyFaces

Tags: jsf, myfaces, trinidad

I understand that the Trinidad framework is an extension of MyFaces project (who is the JSF implementation). But, I have JSF project that has only the trinidad dependencies. So, I ask:

- How works this project without the JSF implementation´s dependencies?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the project which you've in hands is been targeted for deployment on a real Java EE application server.

Normally, JSF is already provided as part of the [Java EE API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api) by a decent Java EE application server such as Glassfish, JBoss AS, WebSphere, WebLogic, etc. The web application project does not need to include the JSF libraries at all (like as it does not ever need to include the JSP/Servlet/EJB/JPA/etc libraries when deployed to such a server).

However, in case of barebones JSP/Servlet containers like Tomcat and Jetty, JSF is not provided by the server itself. JSF has either to be manually installed in those containers or to be provided by the web application project itself.

JSF component libraries like Trinidad, PrimeFaces, RichFaces, etc are not part of the Java EE API and thus surely need to be supplied by the web application project itself.